# Vite not respecting server.watch.ignored option (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm using Laravel 10  with Inertia and Vite. The `/resources/stuff/` folder contains a very large amount of subfolders and files which I don't want to be watched while running Vite. This is to avoid getting "`ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached`".

My vite.config.js contains the following option:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ["/resources/stuff/"],
    },
  },
  ...
});
```

Yet when I do `npm run dev`, I still get `ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached` on a file inside the ignored folder.

How can I get Vite to skip `/resources/stuff/` while watching for file changes? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I'd rather not just increase the operating system's maximum file watchers, as the folder contains more than 80,000 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your path is incorrect. `/resources` would refer to an absolute path in your filesystem root, wouldn't it? Seems like this would be a better match

```js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ["**/resources/stuff/**"],
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the path on server.watch.ignored was relative to the project's root.

Comment: @lampyridae it might be, but paths starting with `/` are not relative. You might have been thinking of `./`

Comment: "resources/stuff/" doesn't work either so it seems the recursive wildcards are necessary.